# How to order by value enumeration statuses?

Tags: c#, enums

I have this foreach and how can i order by so that i get last item on first palce and the others to stay where they are?

```
  foreach (Statuses val in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Statuses)))
    {
       Status.Add(new StatusModel() 
         { 
            Value = (string)val.ToString(), 
            TransKey = val.ToString() 
         });
    }
```

Comment: Is `Status` a `List`?

Comment: Is your Transkey always going to be unique?

Comment: yes it will be always unique

Comment: ok..than I think the second solution from Dave is a good one

Comment: Not sure if this is what you need, but you can use something like `Status = Status.Skip(Status.Count - 1).Take(1).Concat(Status.Take(Status.Count - 1)).ToList();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this dirty trick:

```
var ordered = Status
    .OrderByDescending(s => s.TransKey == "ValueYouWantAtTheTop");
```

Probably more efficient option:

```
var toMoveToTop = Status.First(s => s.TransKey == "ValueYouWantAtTheTop");
Status.Remove(toMoveToTop);
Status.Insert(0, toMoveToTop);
```

Comment: @fubo OrderBy uses a stable sort, so they will.

Comment: Yes, try `Enumerable.Range(1, 10).OrderByDescending(i => i == 4)` for example. Results in `4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10`. --- assuming "the others to stay where they are" means "in the same sequence", not "at the same index".

Comment: @DaveBish how will i call that ordered then?

Comment: @None - `ordered` is an `IEnumerable<StatusModel>` you can `foreach` over it, like you could with any list-like object. Or, if you want to materialize it into a "real" list, you could for example call `Status = ordered.ToList();`.